# Group concate over rows with limitation

Tags: r, dataframe

Could someone please give an advice how to solve the following problem:

Concate over rows for each `ID` with limitation that only `ID`s are considered which have at least one `type = C` in their type-flow:

```
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
type<-c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","D")
mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(ID,type))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option using `aggregate` and `ave`

```
aggregate(type~ID, mydata[ave(mydata$type == "C", mydata$ID, FUN = any), ], 
      function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "->"))

#ID       type
#1  1 A->B->C->D
#2  2 A->B->C->D
```

Logic is same as @A. Suliman's post, we filter the dataframe with `ave` and `aggregate` `type` variable by `ID` and `paste` them together.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr) 
mydata %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter("C" %in% type) %>% 
            #filter(any(type == 'C')) %>% #as Ronak suggest
            #filter(length(unique(type))==4) %>% #OR using length and unique
            summarise(type_flow=paste(type, collapse="->"))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   ID    type_flow      
  <fct> <chr>     
1 1     A->B->C->D
2 2     A->B->C->D
```

Comment: @flobrr Did you use `group_by`. if you did not use `group_by(ID)` then, of course, you will get one row. Also if you have `plyr` loaded then of load it.

Comment: I exectued your whole code. The issue was caused by loaded plyr package. Thanks for your supplement. Now it works

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table:

```
setDT(mydata)
idsWC <- mydata[type == "C", unique(ID)]
mydata[ID %in% idsWC, paste(type, collapse = "->"), ID]
   ID         V1
1:  1 A->B->C->D
2:  2 A->B->C->D
```